# Dart - Circular imports

Tags: flutter, dart, circular-dependency

In other languages (like Python, Go, C#, etc.), circular imports are an issue and the program doesn't run. However, Dart seems to get around this issue and different Dart files can import each other. I am curious about how Dart handles this, and to get to know if there are any gotchas about it.

I tried searching online but couldn't get anything meaningful.

Comment: I think Dart's compiler just copies all code into a single file, and just compiles that one file, so it doesn't have to deal with multiple files.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Usually, the circular dependencies are allowed for languages using a [multi-pass compiler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-pass_compiler).

The logic behind it is that the compiler parses and analyses the code multiple times, and generates intermediate code after each stage.

About Dart, the VM offers a Just-In-Time (JIT) and an Ahead Of Time (AOT) compilers as [explained here](https://dart.dev/overview), which also work with intermediate code.
I didn't play much with Dart's compiler but I guess the implemented logic is the one of a multi-pass compiler